# how to resolve Firebase image upload shows permission issues

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I was trying to implement image upload using firebase storage. When I post the file via front end application its gives me an error,

```
error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Permission denied. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."
```

}

i have set the permission as below,

```
 rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

can anybody know about this issue? I was trying for the past few days and I couldn't find the solution. I appreciate all your answers.

Comment: Have you set the right permissions?

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
this is the permission i have set

Comment: Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#public) out.

Comment: Seems to be an issue affecting many users in a certain region. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70054644/wyh-i-can-not-upload-file-to-firebase-storage/70055919#70055919 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053565/firebase-storage-credentials-missing-for-googleapis-com-issue/70055973#70055973

Answer (score 4):

*firebaser here*

There was a problem with permissions on the default storage bucket for projects created in the past few days. This problem has been addressed a few hours ago, so should not be occurring in projects that you create from now on.

For any projects affected, you can fix the problem by following these steps:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser and select the affected project.
2. Select the default bucket and click <kbd>SHOW INFO PANEL</kbd>
3. Click the <kbd>ADD PRINCIPAL</kbd> buton in the right pane .
4. Add `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com` as the new principal,
5. Grant the role <kbd>Cloud Storage for Firebase Service Agent</kbd> and click <kbd>SAVE</kbd>.
6. Verify that the permission was successfully granted.

Comment: How do you know if you are affected? Is the `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com` not present then ? I cant find SHOW INFO PANEL button.. is it still named like that ? The role `Cloud Storage for Firebase Service Agent` does not exist either