# Wyh I can not upload file to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload jpg file to Firebase Storage. Here is my issue:

```
fun sharePost(view: View) {
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        val uniqueImgName = "${uuid}.jpg"
        
        val imgReference = storage.reference.child("images").child(uniqueImgName)

        selectedImage?.let{ 
            imgReference.putFile(it).addOnFailureListener { e ->
                println(e.localizedMessage)
            }.addOnSuccessListener { 
                println("passed")
            }
        }
}
```

Logcat:

```
W/NetworkRequest:No App Check token for request.
V/NativeCrypto:SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xe9f83e78: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242 0xce199040:0x00000000)
W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/postapp-3224.appspot.com/o
```

and Firebase Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Durin the time you you reported this, we had reports from some developers in Turkey being unable to access Cloud Storage with their ISP. The problem was gone a few days later.

I recommend testing with another connection to verify if you're in the same situation. If it works on another connection, you should probably reach out to your ISP to see if they can explain the problem.

I'd also [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) who are tracking the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue and after hours of checking everything, I finally upgraded the dependency version from:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
->
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
```

Hopefully this fix will help others.

Thanks